# How to create the object with text

Tags: java

I got text from files from directory and it subdirectories with method below. I got this:

```
Mar  5 10:00:15 gw1-nc-biva transaction0:  O365-1033,O365-104
Mar  5 10:00:15 gw1-nc-biva transaction0: Asset id: 3887
Mar  5 10:00:15 gw1-nc-biva transaction0: Captured transactions: 
Mar  5 10:00:15 gw1-nc-biva transaction0:  Atlas-1,Atlas-10
Mar  5 10:00:15 gw1-nc-biva transaction0: Asset id: 3888
Mar  5 10:00:15 gw1-nc-biva transaction0: Captured transactions: 
Mar  5 10:00:15 gw1-nc-biva transaction0:  Google-1,Google-136
Mar  5 10:00:15 gw1-nc-biva transaction1: Log time: Mon, 05 Mar 2018 18:00:05 GMT
Mar  5 10:00:15 gw1-nc-biva transaction1: Asset id: 3886
.
.
.
```

I want to create from this an object and write to an `ArrayList`. How can I do this?

```
public static void pathFiles(File folder) throws IOException {
    File[] folderEntries = folder.listFiles();
    for (File entry : folderEntries) {
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            pathFiles(entry);
            continue;
        }

    Files.lines(Paths.get(entry.getPath())).forEach(System.out::println); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) What object? (2) Easy: parse fields, construct, `ArrayList::add`.

Comment: How i can parse fields and create construct

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear what you are asking here, since you don't give any info about **the object** nor **the arraylist**.

However, assuming that you want to collect the file contents in a list
you are almost there. Just use a `Collector` instead of printing the lines like so:

```
List<String> lines;

try {
  lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(entry.getPath())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Could not read the file.");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```